# xdvi not showing pages of tex file

Tags: errors

I am using the commands:

```
latex <filename>.tex
xdvi <filename>.dvi
```

The document is compiling fine but in the xdvik viewer only the first page is visible. I am unable to understand why is it happening. I think it is because of some error in the code. Can you point out the error I am making in the code? The images are not causing a problem, i.e after removing the code for the figure (image to be inserted) also I am not able to view the rest of the pages in xdvik.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\author{Name}
\title{Doc Name}
\usepackage{graphics} 
\begin{document}
% generates the title
\maketitle
\newpage
% insert the table of contents
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Acknowledgement}
\paragraph{We wish to thank .....}
\newpage

\section{Abstract}
\paragraph{Our project is ....}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{Name1.eps}
\caption{cap1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{Name2.eps}
\caption{cap2}
\end{figure}

\section{Introduction}
\paragraph{....}

\section{Design Approach}
\paragraph{.....Aribitrary paragraph follows.Mrs. Southcott had recently attained her five-and-
twentieth blessed birthday, of whom a prophetic private in
the Life Guards had heralded the sublime appearance by
announcing that arrangements were made for the
swallowing up of London and Westminster. Even the
Cock-lane ghost had been laid only a round dozen of
years, after rapping out its messages, as the spirits of this
very year last past (supernaturally deficient in originality)
rapped out theirs. Mere messages in the earthly order of
events had lately come to the English Crown and People,
from a congress of British subjects in America: which,
strange to relate, have proved more important to the
human race than any communications yet received
through any of the chickens of the Cock-lane brood.
France, less favoured on the whole as to matters
spiritual than her sister of the shield and trident, rolled
with exceeding smoothness down hill, making paper
money and spending it. Under the guidance of her
Christian pastors, she entertained herself, besides, with
such humane achievements as sentencing a youth to have
his hands cut off, his tongue torn out with pincers, and his
body burned alive, because he had not kneeled down in
the rain to do honour to a dirty procession of monks
which passed within his view, at a distance of some fifty or
}

\section{Software Design}
\paragraph{.....Arbitrary paragraph follows.the latter, when every posting-house and ale-house could
produce somebody in ‘the Captain’s’ pay, ranging from
the landlord to the lowest stable non-descript, it was the
likeliest thing upon the cards. So the guard of the Dover
mail thought to himself, that Friday night in November,
one thousand seven hundred and seventy-five, lumbering
up Shooter’s Hill, as he stood on his own particular perch
behind the mail, beating his feet, and keeping an eye and a
hand on the arm-chest before him, where a loaded
blunderbuss lay at the top of six or eight loaded horse-
pistols, deposited on a substratum of cutlass.
}

\section{Hardware Design}
\paragraph{......}

\section{Conclusions and Future Work}
\paragraph{......}

\section{References}
\paragraph{}

\ldots{} The End
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but `\paragraph` is a _sectioning_ command like `\section` and is not meant to hold an entire paragraph of text! (Structurally, it comes below `\subsubsection`.) Before tackling anything else I'd recommend you fix this.

Comment: sometimes, xdvi simply isn't capable of handling random postscript code.  however, in my experience, that usually results in a page with "garbage" instead of a coherent figure, not the entire absence of a page.  but in any event, i've always seen a helpful warning message in the window from which xdvi was launched.  (i always launch from a command line, not from within an editor or gui.)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you people for answering. I used `dvipdf Myfile.dvi` to view the dvi file as pdf and I am able to view the document perfectly.